# site home not at site root index

Tags: seo, google, redirects, 301-redirect, best-practices

I have an SEO concern with a website that has just finished the development stage, basically the site has been in progress for a year. During this period the site has been accessible from the URL: `/home/index.php` along with a landing page (construction) at: `/`

It is time to launch and I need to know what to do. Should I go through the site and change all links to the homepage to the site root index (where the construction page currently is), or can I do some form of redirecting that will not negatively effect SEO.

Can I 301 redirect `/index.php` to go to `/home/` OR should I move the homepage content to `/index.php` and do a redirect on `/home/index.php` to point to the site root `index.php`

What is the best solution that is SEO friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution in terms of SEO would be to ensure that your homepage loads at `/` (root) and all other possible variations redirect to `/` accordingly.

This of course depends on exactly what you have loading at `/` currently however and what platform / CMS your site sits on.

Typically, you would look to 301 redirect `/index.php` and `/home` and `/home/index.php` to `/` and ensure that your homepage content resides at `/`. All of which can be implemented via your root `.htaccess` on an Apache server. Then serve `/` (www.domain.com) as the [canonical](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) URL for your homepage.

If you require more depth to this answer, please advise what content is currently served in your site's root and what CMS / platform your site is using.

Comment: Yes, I was figuring this was the case. I think best scenario is just to take the time to get the files in the right place, and the links pointing to the right location. index.php belongs at `/`

Comment: It would likely be better to use RewriteRule for this as well by the way. Best of luck with it.